# How do I add points of skill tags getting for every correct main question and subquestions?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

[image]I would like to add the points of skill tags(1,2,3,4 consider as 4 skills) each of  these skill tag (any number of skills)has 1 point and add each tag to main questions and sub questions. Once the student has give the correct answer for the question(main questions and sub questions), it should add the points to the main question and sub questions(if student gave correct answer to main question it redirects to next main question instead of sub question)using the Django Rest Framework with one API call.

How do i can save it. Thanks!

Comment: Mind sharing the current code that you have for that? It would help to understand your question better!

Comment: Actually i don't have code. I just know the concept. You want me to explain more clear?

Comment: That would help, yes.

Comment: consider a folder which contains main questions and subquestions. Teacher create those questions with skill tags( core skill, knowledge skill, exam skill, foundation skill). Now student is taking his exam, first he will get main question, if he do well we have to add the points to that main question. For suppose he did mistake the main question, we have to give sub questions which relates to main question it also has skill tags. If he do correct here we should add the points of main and subquestions.

Comment: Still problem statement is not very clear, please do share some examples also.

Comment: Now i sent image, Is it clear to understand